# How to use nextSibling in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="p1">1</p>
    <p id="p2">2</p>
    <p id="p3">3</p>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("p2").nextSibling.nodeValue="9";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

From my understanding, `document.getElementById("p2")` is the second element P, then its `nextSibling` should be the third element,and I set this element's text value to "9", but the output is 1,2,9,3, but I expected to see 1,2,9.

Where did I go wrong? And why I can't use  `document.getElementById("p2").nextSibling.innerHTML="9"`, because it just prints nothing?

Comment: Use `.nextElementSibling` and set its `.textContent`. You were getting the text node representing the whitespace between the two `p` elements, and were settings its text. The `.innerHTML` didn't display anything because that property has no meaning for text nodes.

Answer (score 2):

In your specific example the `nextSibling` is a textNode (the line-break between the `p#p2` and `p#p3` elements), and not the next `p` element. You might want to use `nextElementSibling` instead.

Note also that you would want to use `textContent` instead of `nodeValue`.

Here is the change to your code:

```js
document.getElementById("p2").nextElementSibling.textContent="9";
```

```html
<p id="p1">1</p>
<p id="p2">2</p>
<p id="p3">3</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

> From my understanding, document.getElementById("p2") is the second element P, then its nextSibling should be the third element,and I set this element's text value to "9", but the output is 1,2,9,3, but I expected to see 1,2,9.

Siblings include [ignorable text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace_in_the_DOM), not just elements.